# Transparent child form in parent form with transparency and background

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with background image and transparency key.
In that form I put child form which must be fully transparent to show bakground of the parent form. If I set another transparency key to child form - it do not get transparency at all, and if i set transparency key of parent form - child cut through parent form's background image.

I need to use form - not user control so thats an issue. And i dont want to set dublicate background image to child form.

Im working visually. Here's code from designer:

1. That is my parent

   ```
       // 
       // Main
       // 
       this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
       this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
       this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
       this.BackgroundImage = global::NWN_Tsuki.Properties.Resources.Book;
       this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
       this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 665);
       this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
       this.Controls.Add(this.CloseBtn);
       this.DoubleBuffered = true;
       this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
       this.KeyPreview = true;
       this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 665);
       this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 665);
       this.Name = "Main";
       this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
       this.Text = "Header";
       this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
       this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Main_KeyDown);
       this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Main_MouseDown);
       this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
       this.ResumeLayout(false);
   ```
2. That is how I insert child into parent's panel:

   ```
       private void LeftPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
       ToC toc = new ToC();
       toc.TopLevel = false;
       toc.AutoScroll = true;
       this.LeftContent.Controls.Add(toc);
       toc.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
       toc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       toc.Show(); 
   }
   ```
3. Here is my Child:

   ```
       // 
       // ToC
       // 
       this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
       this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
       this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
       this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(428, 396);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch7Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch6Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch5Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch4Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch3Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch2Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Ch1Btn);
       this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
       this.Name = "ToC";
       this.Text = "ToC";
       this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
       this.ResumeLayout(false);
   ```

Thats the situation when child is Silver inside parent now matter that it has transparency key Silver.
If i set `this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;` to Child - it will pierce parent's background.

Here's some images of what i mean.

[Child with other then parent transparency key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrGHv.jpg)

[Child with same as parent transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPEA6.jpg)

Comment: Show us some code so that we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your child form's background is piercing the main form. 
There are two things you might try.

1. try setting both to a different color which your are most likely not going to use. Like `Color.Magenta`. (Altough I understand that you might have tried this already)
2. You should be able to set the Back color to transparent [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.transparent(v=vs.110).aspx)

   Button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

Comment: Well, i tried this with DarkRed in example. If both has same color - child pierces parent. If child has other color - it dont get transparency.

The problem is i need to set Transparent color to whole form, not a single element, because i show form in panel. If i set contol color transparent - it will be transparent relative it's parent - my "child" form. And child form still will not be transparent at all or will pierce parent.

Comment: Does your Main need that transparencykey? maybe that is the reason it is piercing it

Comment: Yes, it need transparency, cause main reason is background image in PNG-8 format  give effect of simple opened book on the screen without any borders. You can see it on screenshots - there is launched solution where you can notice book without borders.

Comment: Well i tried to remove transparency from main form. Same effect. So thats not an issue.
Child or not transparent at all, or perces parent even if parent without transparency.

Comment: Also then you set the transparencykey of the main and the parent's backcolor to darkred and then the main backcolor and child transparencykey to another color like blue. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Example:
Parent Back.Color = DarkRed; Transparency Key = DarkRed;
Child BackColor = DarkRed; TrKey = Any; Result = Piercing.

Parent Back.Color = Any; Tr.Key = DarkRed;
Child Back.Color = DarkRed; TrKey = Any; Result = Piercing.

Parent BackColor = Any; Tr.Key = Any or None (no matter same (transparent) or different (non transparent));
Child Back.Color = Any; TrKey = Any (same as Back); Result = Without transparency at all.